# for-loop with included initialization syntactically and semantically correct?

Tags: java, android

I wonder if the following code snippet is an elegant and efficient replacement that really is 100% semantically identical. Especially, is the declaration and initialization inside the `for` a good idea:

```
for ( BroadcastReceiver br : new BroadcastReceiver[] {receiverA, receiverB, receiverC} )
    if ( br != null ) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver( br );
        } catch ( Exception ignored ) {}
    }
```

Instead of:

```
    if ( receiverA != null ) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver( receiverA );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {}
    }
    if ( receiverB != null ) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver( receiverB );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {}
    }
    if ( receiverC != null ) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver( receiverC );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {}
    }
```

(I know that an extra array is created and the for-overhead is also necessary but at the same time I save the code repetitions and the question for the reader if all these repetitions really are identical)

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: This type of question,is not for Stack Overflow, but for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would do it the first way, to avoid code repetition. Stay [**DRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: No, I cannot confirm *syntactical* identity, since the code is obviously syntactically different. They are functionally (semantically) the same, though.

Comment: An alternative to the loop would be to define a method, say, `maybeUnregisterReceiver`, and invoke once for each of the `BroadcastReceivers`.

Comment: The wording "syntactically identical" was wrong, sorry for that. I meant "syntactically correct" and all the answers suggest yes. I was also concerned about the additional array and its overhead, but ... anyway

Comment: People worry too much about micro-optimizations. It's much more important that the code is readable rather than save a few nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet indeed looks better than the duplicated statements.

You could also implement a separate helper method with vararg and then invoke it with arbitrary number of arguments:

```java
public void unregisterReceivers(BroadcastReceiver ... receivers) {
    for (BroadcastReceiver br : receivers)
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(br);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                // at least log exception that some receiver failed to unregister
            }
        }
    }
}

unregisterReceivers(receiverA, receiverB, receiverC);
```

Comment: That looks really nice! Thanks to let me learn